# How to implement Custom Data Structure for ink! storage?

Tags: ink, smart-contract, rust

I want to create custom data structure. I'm a newbie with Rust and Ink! and can't get how to implement my data structure to use it in `Mapping`.
I have such a structure:

```
pub struct TokenInfo {
    data: [u8; 284],
    in_collection: bool,
    init_price: Balance,
    init_owner: AccountId,
    for_sale: bool,
    discount_duration: u64,
    birth_date: Timestamp,
}
```

1. Should I implement it as a structure and add a `Mapping` field of that structure to my storage or implement it as separated values and add a `Mapping` field to each of it to my storage?
2. I found something close to my problem on this site https://ink.substrate.io/datastructures/custom-datastructure but there's only example with one `bool` variable.

- How to implement `SpreadLayout` for my structure with a bunch of different variables?
- How to calculate `FOOTPRINT`? Guess I should add 1 for every `i32`. But what's about `u8`? Divide by 4? What's about bool? In example above there's added 1 only for one `bool` variable. I understand that you can't lock half of a storage cell but don't understand how should I calculate the `FOOTPRINT`. I'm really confused about it. I got 82 for `FOOTPRINT`, does my calculations right?
- Also I don't understand how to implement functions: `pull_spread()`, `push_spread()` and `clear_spread()`. How to handle a lot of variables in these functions?

3. How to use structure implemented as a `SpreadLayout`? I have an error of `unsatisfied trait bounds` when trying to get value of the structure with `get()` function of `Mapping` or when trying to set value with `insert()` function. Should I use new functions: `pull_spread()`, `push_spread()` and `clear_spread()` instead?

Comment: re question 1: consider that doing a `Mapping` with the entire struct means that you'll r/w every field whenever you want to w/r just a single field, which means wasteful storage io and expensive fees for simple contract calls.

Comment: Hey, are you deriving the `SpreadAllocate` trait on your root storage struct and using `initialize_contract`? Both of these are necessary when working with `Mappings`.

As for the `SpreadLayout` trait, you shouldn't need to implement it manually since you're working with primitive types - so if you do need to implement such traits (which I don't think you do in this case) you can simply derive them.

Comment: @BernardoRodrigues Thanks for your answer. It is really helpful because I will write every field only on initialize an instance but after will read/write 1-3 fields. I misunderstood of that concept a little because my previous blockchain was Tezos where you create a lot of structures and add them to `Mapping` without any problem.

Comment: @HCastano No, I am trying to derive `SpreadAllocate` for secondary storage and want to have a `Mapping` to `TokenInfo` structure in my root storage.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I think we need to clarify some things about ink! storage.

> It is really helpful because I will write every field only on initialize an instance but after will read/write 1-3 fields

So in ink! [all reads storage are eager](https://ink.substrate.io/datastructures/overview#eager-loading).

What this means is that whenever this is read from storage, the *entire* struct will be
read, even if just a *single field* is accessed.

For example:

```rust
#[ink(storage)]
pub struct ContractStorage {
    foo: u32,
    bar: AccountId,
}

#[ink(message)]
fn read_from_storage(&mut self) {
    // This reads the _entire_ `ContractStorage` struct from storage, which includes the
    // `bar` field.
    let foo = self.foo;
    todo!()
}
```

> No, I am trying to derive SpreadAllocate for secondary storage and want to have a Mapping to TokenInfo structure in my root storage.

So there is not such thing as secondary storage. At the end of the day
you only have fields in the root storage struct (the one tagged with
`#[ink(storage)]`.

Now, for the custom struct in a `Mapping` part. The `Mapping` API basically requires that
your type implements `scale::Encode`, `scale::Decode`, `SpreadLayout`, and `PackedLayout`
(see the requirements for [`Mapping::insert()`](https://docs.rs/ink_storage/latest/ink_storage/struct.Mapping.html#method.insert)).

Since your `TokenInfo` struct is made up of primitive types, which themselves implement
all these traits, then you can simply derive those traits for `TokenInfo`. No need to manually implement them.

```rust
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]

use ink_lang as ink;

#[ink::contract]
mod flipper {
    use ink_storage::traits::{SpreadAllocate, PackedLayout, SpreadLayout};

    #[derive(PackedLayout, SpreadLayout, scale::Encode, scale::Decode)]
    #[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(::scale_info::TypeInfo))]
    pub struct TokenInfo {
        data: [u8; 284],
        in_collection: bool,
        init_price: Balance,
        init_owner: AccountId,
        for_sale: bool,
        discount_duration: u64,
        birth_date: Timestamp,
    }

    #[ink(storage)]
    #[derive(SpreadAllocate)]
    pub struct Flipper {
        map: ink_storage::Mapping<u32, TokenInfo>,
    }

    impl Flipper {
        #[ink(constructor)]
        pub fn default() -> Self {
            ink_lang::utils::initialize_contract(|_| {})
        }

        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn flip(&mut self) {
            let s = TokenInfo {
                data: [0; 284],
                in_collection: Default::default(),
                init_price: Default::default(),
                init_owner: Default::default(),
                for_sale: Default::default(),
                discount_duration: Default::default(),
                birth_date: Default::default(),
            };

            self.map.insert(&0, &s);
        }
    }
}
```